# Vue.js - cannot assign new value to property using keyup.enter event on input binded to that property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have inputs that have @keyup.enter event assigned with method to reset value of variables binded to these inputs to null. Basically, like this:

```
methods:{

    clear: function () {
        this.something1 = null;
        this.something2 = null;
    }

},


<input type="text" v-model="something1" @keyup.enter="clear">
<input type="text" v-model="something2" @keyup.enter="clear">
```

For some reason, this doesnt works for input that received keyup event. Other input gets cleared correctly. How can i fix it?

Comment: `something1` in `clear`, but `something` in the binding

Comment: Thats just typo in this example, thanks for mentioning but it didnt helped.

Comment: Where is `something1` and `something2` initially defined? In `data` or `props`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you present above works as expected (even without `data` being pre-set). There must be some other issue at work.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  methods: {
    clear: function() {
      this.something1 = null;
      this.something2 = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" v-model="something1" @keyup.enter="clear">
<input type="text" v-model="something2" @keyup.enter="clear">
```

Comment: Actually i set them, and I just skipped it from my code shown here - my bad.

Comment: @PeterPe I have updated my code to be the same as the code in your question, and it still works. If the Snippet here works for you, there is something else going on in your code.